# Extend a function stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large JavaScript project that makes several Ajax web service calls.  The  code to handle the web service calls comes from a shared external file.

To separate the web service from calling code, there is a global object to reference to the calling function like so

```
var doRemote ={};
$(document).ready(function(){
doRemote =getRemoteEndpoint('https://someplace.org/MyWebService.aspx');
}
```

A simplified version of the getRemoteEndpoint, which is in a file shared by several other pages in addition to the one I'm working on is as follows:

```
function getRemoteEndpoint(url) {
    return function(methodName, options) {
        var extension = {
            url: url + '/' + methodName,
            data: {},
            async: true

        };

        var combined = $.extend({}, extension, options);
        combined.data = JSON.stringify(combined.data);
        return $.ajax( combined );
    };
}
```

I invoke the web service calls by the following code

```
doRemote('WebServiceMethodName', 
    {
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Web Service Returned' + data);
        },
        error: function(req, stat, err) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

I have the need to execute a function before executing the getRemoteEndpoint call in only the page I'm working on.  Instead of calling the function before each of the 30 web service calls, I'd like to add a line of code to the function.  I've tried to replace the doRemote assignment with the following.

```
doRemote =function() {
                DoTask();
                return getRemoteEndpoint('https://someplace.org/MyWebService.aspx');
    };
```

DoTask is a named function in the program I'm working on.  While it throws no errors, none of the Ajax calls work.

I tried to use the JQuery.extend function, but it didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: comment doTask() and try. If it works there is an error in DoTask(). i dont see any other issues

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. What does DoTask() look like?

Comment: I tried commenting out the function call, and it didn't work.  The DoTask Function has already been tested and works with no errors.  I realized, after coding and testing it, that I needed to invoke before each web service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually call it to assign the **result** of `getRemoteEndpoint` to `doRemote`:

```
doRemote = (function() {
    DoTask();
    return getRemoteEndpoint('https://someplace.org/MyWebService.aspx');
})();
```

Update:

```
doRemote = (function() {
    var oldDoRemote = getRemoteEndpoint('https://someplace.org/MyWebService.aspx');
    return function(a1, a2) {
      DoTask();
      oldDoRemote(a1, a2);
    }
})();
```

Comment: That works, but doesn't do want I wanted to do.  The code creates a closure, which executes the DoTask() function once, upon the assignment of the function to doRemote.  What I wanted was to fire DoTask() each time doRemote is invoked.

Comment: The first code does not create a closure. See my update.